# Get customer group price

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price

In the `sales_order_save_after` event I am processing the order. Using `getPrice()` I get the original price of the product. How do I get the price according to my current user group?

```
$quote =  Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order['quote_id']);
$items = $quote->getItemsCollection()->getItems();
foreach ($items as $order_item)
{
    #$product = $order_item->getProduct();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $order_item->getProductId() );
    Mage:Log( round($product->getPrice(), 2) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getFinalPrice()` does the trick:

```
Mage:Log( round($product->getFinalPrice(), 2) );
```